# Prevent IE7 from treating cached ajax response synchonously

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

IE7 appears to be caching the response from an ajax request. When the response is cached, it behaves as if the request is synchronous, calling my callback as soon as it is passed to jQuery.get, rather than waiting for the current call stack to return.

For now I'm going to put a short timeout in my callback, which will hopefully get my code to work at least. Is there a better way to prevent this from happening? To force IE7 to wait until the current call stack is finished before calling the callback?

Here's a simplified example of the behavior I'm seeing:

```
myDebugger.log("setting up ajax request");
jQuery.get(myUrl, function(){
   myDebugger.log("ajax request returned")
});
myDebugger.log("finished setting up ajax request");
```

The first time I run this in IE7 after restarting the browser, I get:

```
setting up ajax request
finished setting up ajax request
ajax request returned
```

The second time I run this in IE7 I get this:

```
setting up ajax request
ajax request returned
finished setting up ajax request
```

Comment: happened to me too. You can disable cache by `ajax({url: "...", cache: false}`